# how can I retrieve the latest 5 blog posts on the homepage of my docpad website?

Tags: docpad

I have been testing docpad as CMS and I want to know how can I display in my homepage the latest 5 posts from the blog.

I have looked for examples but no luck so far.

Do i need some plugin for that functionality? at the moment im using the following modules:

```
"docpad-plugin-marked": "~2.1.1",
"docpad-plugin-stylus": "~2.3.0",
"docpad-plugin-coffeekup": "~2.1.5",
"docpad-plugin-cleanurls": "~2.4.3",
"docpad-plugin-coffeescript": "~2.2.1",
"docpad": "~6.32.0",
"docpad-plugin-minicms": "~2.1.1"
```

Answer (score 5):

In the docpad.coffee file under collections I have

```
posts: ->   
   @getCollection('documents').findAllLive({relativeOutDirPath:path.join('blog','post')},[date:-1])
```

I suppose the key here is the ordering of the collection by the date attribute ("date:-1")

Then in your "eco" file you can access the collection using:  @getCollection('posts'). This will, of course, give you all your posts - so if you just want the last n posts then you just take the first n documents in the collection.

```
 <% for document in  @getCollection('posts').toJSON().slice(0,5): %>
<li>
  <a href="<%=document.url%>" title="<%=document.title%>"><%=document.title%>
  </a>
</li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a plugin, you can use the in-built `@getFilesAtPath`helper

For example I store my blog posts in `src/documents/blog` and on my home page I am using

```
<% for post in @getFilesAtPath("blog").findAll().toJSON() %>
  <a href="<%= post.url %>">
    <%= post.title %>
  </a>
<% end %>
```

I haven't read the documentation properly for the collections in docpad, so I used a quick *hack* with `Array#slice` to limit my blog posts to **3**

```
<% for post in @getFilesAtPath("blog").findAll().toJSON().slice(0, 3) %>
```